# On graded fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings, graded-algebras

Tom Marly  [here](https://www.math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/905notes.pdf) noted that

> if R is a graded field then $R$ is concentrated in degree 0, i.e., $R=R_0$ and $R_n =0$ for all $n \neq 0$.

Is this proposition  mentioned in any book or paper ??  please, I need to document this proposition.

Thank you.

Comment: Who is Tom Marly ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I put the link, thank u

Comment: It's Tom Marley, from University of Nebraska.

Comment: @ZachTeitler yes but this is "Note" not paper  " my university except only books and papers in references".

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is a $\mathbf Z$-graded field then it is easy to see that $k := R_0$ is a field. When $R_0$ is a field there are two possibilities:

1. $R = k$
2. $R \cong k[x, x^{-1}]$

For suppose that $R \ne k$ and let $\pi \in R$ be homogeneous of minimal positive degree. If $x$ is an indeterminate over $k$ with $\deg x = \deg \pi$, then we obtain a graded map

$$ \phi : k[x,x^{-1}] \to R, $$

by sending $x$ to $\pi$. The kernel of $\phi$ is a graded ideal of degree $0$ (i.e. $\ker \phi \subseteq k$) thus $\ker \phi = 0$. This shows that $\phi$ is injective.

To see that $\phi$ is surjective, let $\alpha \in R \setminus \operatorname{Im} \phi$ be of minimal positive degree. Since $\pi$ has minimal positive degree in $R$, $\deg \pi^{-1} \alpha \ge 0$. Since $\alpha$ has minimal positive degree in $R \setminus \operatorname{Im} \phi$ it follows that $\deg \pi^{-1}\alpha = 0$. But then $\pi^{-1}\alpha \in k$ so $\alpha \in k[\pi, \pi^{-1}] = \operatorname{Im } \phi$.

Therefore, when $R_0$ is a field, either $R = R_0$ or $R$ is a Laurent polynomial ring.

Comment: Thank you .. but I need only the references

Comment: Please, can you mention any reference ?

Comment: @Njl I don't know any reference.

Answer (score 3):

A reference for this fact with a complete proof is Remark 1.3.10 in C. Nastasescu, F. Van Oystaeyen, *Methods of Graded Rings,* Springer 2004.