# Classification of graded fields, semifields, and skew fields

Tags: field-theory, graded-rings, semiring, division-ring

Recently I came upon the following result:

> **Result 1.** Let $K$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded field. Then either $K$ is trivially graded (i.e. $K_k=0$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ with $K_0$ a field or we have $K\cong K_0[x,x^{-1}]$ for $x$ an element of positive even degree.

However, I've found conflicting statements about this: [Lurie's 24th set of lecture notes on chromatic homotopy theory](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/252xnotes/Lecture24.pdf) claims the above result as is, and [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2572406) offers a proof, while  Remark 1.3.10 in Nastasescu–Oystaeyen's *[Methods of Graded Rings](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b94904)* and Exercise 1.1 in [these lecture notes](https://math.unl.edu/%7Etmarley1/905notes.pdf) claim that $K$ must necessarily be trivially graded with $K_0$ a field, not allowing for the case $K\cong K_0[x,x^{-1}]$, i.e., they claim the following result:

> **Result 2.** Let $K$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded field. Then $K$ is trivially graded with $K_0$ a field.

To be precise (and since I suspect this might be an issue with differing definitions), let me precisely define $\mathbb{Z}$-graded fields below:

> **Definition 3.** A **$\mathbb{Z}$-graded field** $K$ consists of
>
> - *The Collection of Abelian Groups.* A collection $\{K_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of abelian groups;
> - *The Multiplication.* A collection of maps
>   $$\mu^{k,\ell}_K\colon K_k\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}K_{\ell}\to K_{k+\ell}$$
>   indexed by $(k,\ell)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, whose action we denote by $(a,b)\mapsto ab$;
> - *The Unit.* A map
>   $$\eta_K\colon\mathbb{Z}\to K_0$$
>   picking an element $1_K$ of $K_0$.
>
> satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. *Associativity.* We have $(ab)c=a(bc)$ for all $a\in K_i$, $b\in K_j$, and $c\in K_k$.
> 2. *Unitality.* We have $1_Ka=a1_K=a$ for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and each $a\in K_k$.
> 3. *Commutativity.* We have $ab=ba$ for all $a\in K_k$ and all $b\in K_\ell$.
> 4. *Invertibility of Nonzero Homogeneous Elements.* For each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and each nonzero $a\in K_k$, there exists an element $a^{-1}$ of $K_{-k}$ such that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=1_K$.

**Question I.** Which result is correct? Result I or Result II?

---

More generally, I'm also interested in what is the situation for graded semifields, graded skew fields, and graded skew semifields.

- [Semifields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semifield) are defined in almost the same way as fields, except that we allow its underlying additive abelian group of it to be just a commutative monoid, i.e. addition can be non-invertible. A famous example is the tropical semiring $(\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\},\max,+,-\infty,0)$.
- [Skew fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring) are also defined similarly to fields, the exception now being that we allow multiplication to be noncommutative. The quaternions are a famous example.
- Lastly, skew semifields are the common generalisation of the above notions: addition can be non-invertible and multiplication noncommutative.

Finally, one defines graded semifields, graded skew fields, and graded skew semifields in a similar way to Definition 3, except that (in order): 1) We ask the $K_k$'s to be just commutative monoids and replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{N}$ and $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$ by $\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}$ everywhere except in the grading 2) We remove condition 3 (commutativity) and 3) we do both of the things in 1) and 2).

**Question II.** Do we have results classifying

1. Graded semifields;
2. Graded skew fields;
3. Graded skew semifields;
4. Graded semifields (resp. skew fields, skew semifields) which are **graded commutative**, i.e. satisfy $ab=(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(a)\mathrm{deg}(b)}ba$;

in a similar vein to Results I/II?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there is some confusion about definitions. First, note that what you wrote is not the definition of a graded field, but of a (commutative) graded ring. Note also that you can replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by any commutative group (actually monoid) $\Gamma$ for the grading.

Then there is the elementary result: in a $\Gamma$-graded ring, if $\Gamma$ is torsion-free then all invertible elements must be homogeneous. It is easy to deduce that, still when $\Gamma$ is torsion-free, if a $\Gamma$-graded ring is a field (not as a graded ring, but simply as a ring, so every non-zero element is invertible), then it is trivially graded.

On the other hand, there is a notion of a graded field: it is a (commutative) graded ring, such that every non-zero *homogeneous* element is invertible. Then of course $K=K_0[x,x^{-1}]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded field. It is actually isomorphic to the group algebra $K_0[\mathbb{Z}]$, and generally speaking, for any $\Gamma$ the group algebra $K_0[\Gamma]$ is a $\Gamma$-graded field. In general the structure of $\Gamma$-graded fields can be rather rich, but in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, the fact that it is projective as an abelian group makes the classification simple.

I don't know much about the general structure of graded semirings, but if you want to learn about graded skew field (also called graded division algebras), then I recommand to you the beginning of "Value Functions on Simple Algebras, and Associated Graded Rings" by Tignol and Wadsworth. Note that they will be a generalization of what I called a graded field. It is still true that a (non-commutative) graded ring over a torsion-free group which is a skew field is trivially graded. You again have to require the non-zero *homogeneous* elements to be invertible, not all non-zero elements.

Comment: Aaagh I forgot to include the field condition indeed! (I've edited the question now.) Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Just to confirm, in the second case, where only the homogeneous elements are required to be invertible, is it indeed the case that the only $\mathbb{Z}$-graded fields are of the form $K_0$ and $K_0[x,x^{-1}]$?

Comment: Also thank you so much for the pointer to Tignol–Wadsworth, it seems there's lots of great stuff there!

Comment: Yes those are the only ones, but in $K_0[x,x^{-1}]$, $x$ can have any degree, which changes the grading. (Basically the non-zero components are those with degree in $n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$, which you can take as the degree of $x$.)

Comment: Thank you for confirming it! I was thinking about this last night and figured out why Lurie said even degree: in that context the $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring comes with the graded-commutativity condition I mentioned in the question body, and then we have $xx^{-1}=(-1)^{\mathrm{deg}(x)\mathrm{deg}(x^{-1})}x^{-1}x$, which forces $\deg(x)$ to be even. As you said though in general $\deg(x)$ can be odd too :)